# How to use a Service Locator in a WCF service

Tags: multithreading, wcf, static, service-locator

I'm using a service locator to hold concrete instances of classes, which is used in a WCF service. Rather than passing the ServiceLocator around I decided to make it static so I could access it from every class. The service locator is populated when the WCF service kicks off and depending on some parameters, it can get populated with different concrete implementations.

My problem is that if a call is made to the WCF service before another call has finished, then (I think) the ServiceLocator will be populated with the incorrect implementations.

Is there any way to make the service locator available to classes and not have it re-used by different threads or calls to the WCF service?

Answer (score 2):

You provide few details about your Service Locator and the undelying implementation. From what I read I understand that it's your own.

My personnal advice is that you should not use a Service Locator in a case of WCF service because WCF exposes some interface that enable dependency injection.

You could read more about the anti pattern Service Locator here : http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx

You should not implement your service locator because there are many OSS project around dependency injection you can use and that do the job the right way.

Here is the correct implementation of Dependency Injection using StructureMap with WCF services  : http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/07/30/integrating-structuremap-with-wcf/.